# gtf2bed only retains gene information

Tags: bed, gtf, gffutils

I want to convert an hg38 [GTF file](http://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-106/gtf/homo_sapiens/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.106.chr.gtf.gz) to bed format using `gtf2bed`:

```
gtf2bed Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.106.gtf > Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.106.gtf.bed
```

It outputs a bed file but it only contains the coordinates for the whole genes and has lost the locations of the exons, UTRs, etc.
While I am running `gtf2bed`, I get thousands of warning like this:

```
WARNING:root:None   21  33276625    33276753    +   three_prime_utr
WARNING:root:WARNING End is after gene end (33279918 > 0)
WARNING:root:WARNING Start is after gene end
WARNING:root:None   21  33279752    33279918    +   three_prime_utr
WARNING:root:WARNING End is after gene end (33283212 > 0)
WARNING:root:WARNING Start is after gene end
WARNING:root:None   21  33283094    33283212    +   three_prime_utr
WARNING:root:WARNING End is after gene end (37101343 > 0)
WARNING:root:WARNING Start is after gene end
WARNING:root:None   21  37100814    37101343    +   transcript
WARNING:root:WARNING End is after gene end (37101343 > 0)
WARNING:root:WARNING Start is after gene end
WARNING:root:None   21  37100814    37101343    +   exon
WARNING:root:WARNING End is after gene end (37237744 > 0)
WARNING:root:WARNING Start is after gene end
WARNING:root:None   21  37221419    37237744    +   transcript
WARNING:root:WARNING End is after gene end (37221597 > 0)
WARNING:root:WARNING Start is after gene end
WARNING:root:None   21  37221419    37221597    +   exon
WARNING:root:WARNING End is after gene end (37237744 > 0)
WARNING:root:WARNING Start is after gene end
WARNING:root:None   21  37237404    37237744    +   exon
```

How can I create a bed file that also contains the coordinates of the other genomic features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this. Be sure to use the latest version of [BEDOPS](https://bedops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and to use the correct command:

```bash
wget http://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-106/gtf/homo_sapiens/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.106.chr.gtf.gz

gtf2bed < <(zcat Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.106.chr.gtf.gz) > Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.106.chr.bed

$ head Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.106.chr.bed
1       1211339 1214153 ENSG00000186827 .       -       ensembl_havana  gene    .       gene_id "ENSG00000186827"; gene_version "11"; gene_name "TNFRSF4"; gene_source "ensembl_havana"; gene_biotype "protein_coding";
1       1211339 1214153 ENSG00000186827 .       -       ensembl_havana  transcript      .       gene_id "ENSG00000186827"; gene_version "11"; transcript_id "ENST00000379236"; transcript_version "4"; gene_name "TNFRSF4"; gene_source "ensembl_havana"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_name "TNFRSF4-201"; transcript_source "ensembl_havana"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; tag "CCDS"; ccds_id "CCDS11"; tag "basic"; transcript_support_level "1 (assigned to previous version 3)";
1       1213982 1214153 ENSG00000186827 .       -       ensembl_havana  exon    .       gene_id "ENSG00000186827"; gene_version "11"; transcript_id "ENST00000379236"; transcript_version "4"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "TNFRSF4"; gene_source "ensembl_havana"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_name "TNFRSF4-201"; transcript_source "ensembl_havana"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; tag "CCDS"; ccds_id "CCDS11"; exon_id "ENSE00001832731"; exon_version "2"; tag "basic"; transcript_support_level "1 (assigned to previous version 3)";
1       1213982 1214127 ENSG00000186827 .       -       ensembl_havana  CDS     0       gene_id "ENSG00000186827"; gene_version "11"; transcript_id "ENST00000379236"; transcript_version "4"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "TNFRSF4"; gene_source "ensembl_havana"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_name "TNFRSF4-201"; transcript_source "ensembl_havana"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; tag "CCDS"; ccds_id "CCDS11"; protein_id "ENSP00000368538"; protein_version "3"; tag "basic"; transcript_support_level "1 (assigned to previous version 3)";
1       1214124 1214127 ENSG00000186827 .       -       ensembl_havana  start_codon     0       gene_id "ENSG00000186827"; gene_version "11"; transcript_id "ENST00000379236"; transcript_version "4"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "TNFRSF4"; gene_source "ensembl_havana"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_name "TNFRSF4-201"; transcript_source "ensembl_havana"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; tag "CCDS"; ccds_id "CCDS11"; tag "basic"; transcript_support_level "1 (assigned to previous version 3)";
```

Finishes without any of the mentioned warnings.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know I should have run it as follows: `gtf2bed < Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.106.gtf > Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.106.gtf.bed`